# Cannot Compile Angular 13 App. Thousands of node_module errors

Tags: .net, angular, visual-studio

I have literally thousands of errors being thrown by Visual Studio 2022 from the node_modules folder. I cannot figure out what I did to cause this to happen as the project was compiling in VS just fine about an hour ago. ng build has no issues compiling and serving the project but I would like to be able to run this from Visual Studio.

Sample of some of the thousands of errors. The format will be error - file:

(TS) Cannot find name 'u64' - Histogram.ts (there are tons of these, as well as 'u8' ones)

(TS) Cannot find name 'u64' - index.d.ts

(TS) Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'PluralRules' - lib.es2018.intl.d.ts

(TS) Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, ImportExportKind, TableKind, ValueType, ExportValue, Exports, ImportValue, ModuleImports, Imports, name, HeadersInit, BodyInit, RequestInfo, BlobPart, DOMHighResTimeStamp, CanvasImageSource, MessageEventSource, ImageBitmapSource, OnErrorEventHandler, TimerHandler, PerformanceEntryList, ReadableStreamReader, ReadableStreamController, VibratePattern, AlgorithmIdentifier, HashAlgorithmIdentifier, BigInteger, NamedCurve, GLenum, GLboolean, GLbitfield, GLint, GLsizei, GLintptr, GLsizeiptr, GLuint, GLfloat, GLclampf, TexImageSource, Float32List, Int32List, GLint64, GLuint64, Uint32List, BufferSource, DOMTimeStamp, FormDataEntryValue, IDBValidKey, Transferable, ReadableStreamDefaultReadResult, BinaryType, CanvasDirection, CanvasFillRule, CanvasLineCap, CanvasLineJoin, CanvasTextAlign, CanvasTextBaseline, ClientTypes, ColorSpaceConversion, EndingType, IDBCursorDirection, IDBRequestReadyState, IDBTransactionMode, ImageOrientation, ImageSmoothingQuality, KeyFormat, KeyType, KeyUsage, NotificationDirection, NotificationPermission, PermissionName, PermissionState, PremultiplyAlpha, PushEncryptionKeyName, PushPermissionState, ReferrerPolicy, RequestCache, RequestCredentials, RequestDestination, RequestMode, RequestRedirect, ResizeQuality, ResponseType, ServiceWorkerState, ServiceWorkerUpdateViaCache, VisibilityState, WebGLPowerPreference, WorkerType, XMLHttpRequestResponseType - lib.dom.ts

(TS) Duplicate index signature of type 'string' - index.d.ts

I would think this seems to point to my tsconfig but I have not been able to figure out what needs to be set or unset. This is a .net 6 app with Angular 13. Below are my packages.config and tsconfig. Please let me know if there is anything else I can provide to make this clearer and thanks a bunch in advance.

packages.json

````
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "prestart": "node aspnetcore-https",
    "start": "run-script-os",
    "start:windows": "ng serve --port 44484 --ssl --ssl-cert %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.pem --ssl-key %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.key",
    "start:default": "ng serve --port 44484 --ssl --ssl-cert $HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.pem --ssl-key $HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.key",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run app:server:dev",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.2",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~12.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.2",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.10.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "~1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "linq-es5": "^1.11.15",
    "oidc-client": "^1.11.5",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "run-script-os": "^1.1.6",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.3"
  }
}```


{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}```
````

Comment: A couple of recommendations... Don't allow major/minor patching in your package.json. Specify exact versions (no `~` or `^`). Also, add an engines value to specify what version, or range of versions, of Node you need to use to compile with.

Comment: Currently dealing with the same issue. Have deleted node_modules folder and npm install again, but issues persists.  The project was building fine, then all of a sudden 4000 errors.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but still seems to occur as it happened to me today. There may be more than one cause for this issue, but this is what solved it for me.

I had added a typescript file to my project and got a prompt to add MS support for typescript files. I accepted and everything continued along just fine.  This morning, when I tried to open the project, I found 4500+ errors, just as described in the original post.

The problem turned out to be the below listed code that was inserted into the .csproj file, likely when I accepted the prompt. I removed those lines and got back to a clean build.

To Brandon's point, my Angular app built fine using ng build, so it had to be something in the visual studio environment, which it was. My VS version is 17.3.5.

As a final point, I have another, far more substantive, angular app that has the below listed code included in the .csproj file and it runs / builds just fine.  Why these VS inclusions cause a problem in one Angular app and not in another is still a bit of a mystery to me, but this info may be helpful if someone is troubleshooting the same problem.

```
    <ItemGroup>
        ...
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" Version="4.8.4">
          <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
          <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>
      
    ...

    <ItemGroup>
        <TypeScriptCompile Include="ClientApp\src\global.ts" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I didn't have to remove the TypeScriptCompile section, but removing the TypeScript.MSBuild section fixed it for me. I'm using VS 17.3.6 and Angular 14.0.3 TypeScript 4.7.4. I was seeing 8,000+ errors while making some small modifications to the built-in  .Net 6.0 WebApp Angular template. And yes, it started happening after clicking through the TypeScript prompt. Thanks John for this solution!

Comment: had to remove newly added components from csproj<ItemGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="ClientApp\src\app\flows\flows.component.ts" />        
  </ItemGroup>

Answer (score 0):

Just as an A B test, try it in VS 2019. I just got a new machine and pulled our repo into VS2022, hit this exact issue. I don't think it has anything to do with your angular app, I was thinking it was a change in MS Build and the VS2022 tools. When I installed 2019 on my box to test them side by side, both 2022 and 2019 just worked. This made trouble shooting it more difficult and not worth the time, but I found this question before getting that far and didn't want to leave you hanging.

We had the exact same symptoms, our solution is an ASP Core 5 app with angular 13 and I was getting a few thousand errors being thrown from our node_modules directory under ClientApp.

I made no code or configuration changes to get it compiling.

VS 2022 install was 17.0.5 and VS 2019 install was 16.11.9.

Hope it helps, but if it doesn't I wouldn't consider angular the problem if you can compile it with ng build locally (I could on mine). It was just my VS 2022 build that was the problem. Also at no point in this process did our build server have an issue which is what made me think it was an MSBuild issue on my machine.